# Javascript Object from External file, program

Tags: javascript, esprima

I am so confused about JavaScript's object system. I know that everything is considered Object in JavaScript but in this code of Esprima, I don't see any statement to declare this project to be accessed with esrpima like the following line: (https://github.com/ariya/esprima/blob/master/esprima.js)

```
var syntax = esprima.parse(text);
```

My question is how and where to define something like `esprima.parse(text)` in Javascript so that it can be exported as external package and be accessed with the object name. I know how to define object like Object = {a: "B"}; but can't find a way to figure this out. Please help me!

```
(function (root, factory) {
    'use strict';

    // Universal Module Definition (UMD) to support AMD, CommonJS/Node.js,
    // Rhino, and plain browser loading.
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['exports'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
        factory(exports);
    } else {
        factory((root.esprima = {}));
    }
}(this, function (exports) {
    'use strict';

    var Token,
        TokenName,
 ...
```

Comment: Please see my answer below. I'm not sure if I fully understood your question. Let me know if something is unclear or I missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it **doesn't**. The variable name, `esprima`, comes from code that **includes** esprima. For example:

```
var esprima = require('esprima');
esprima.parse(text);
```

You could give the variable any other name:

```
var foo = require('esprima');
foo.parse(text);
```

All the the `esprima.js` file does is define an *object* which is exported. It does *not* dictate the *name of the variable* to which the object is assigned to eventually.

---

If the script is loaded in a browser, it actually does define `esprima` explicitly. You can see it in line 55:

```
 factory((root.esprima = {}));
```

This creates an object and assigns it to `root.esprima`. But it's also a function call, so the object is passed to `factory`, which is the function defined in 57, which accept a parameter `exports`. This is where the code assigns all the properties to.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get this, but is "require" the only way to do this? Because in the code I only see the lines with "require"  /*global esprima:true, YUI:true, require:true */  and require(['custom/editor'], function (editor) {   which doesn't really seem related

Comment: And when calling I am not using any require function.function Esprima(text, oid) {
        var syntax = esprima.parse(text);
        document.getElementById(oid).innerHTML = JSON.stringify(syntax);
    }